# Using Async controller action to call existing synchronous method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

I've not dealt much with Async/threads/Tasks other than some web services.

I'm using MVC4. I have existing code which takes some time to run.  It is using an existing method in the service layer, which uses various other the areas in further layers.

Essentially I was hoping to be able to make an ASync call from the Asynccontroller to that method.  However it appears that I would need to change/create another method to implement all the Task & await keywords, quite a hefty job altering all the way down the chain.

Is it possible to call/'fire' a synchronous method in this manner?

I want the long process (creating some documents in the background) to continue running even if the user closes their browser.  However if the user still has the browser open then I would like to return a notification to them.

Is there a better way to fire a background task to execute from the MVC Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to use `async` for something it cannot do. As I describe on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

> Is it possible to call/'fire' a synchronous method in this manner?

Sort of. You can use `Task.Run` if you have CPU-bound work that you want to move off the UI thread in a desktop/mobile application. But there is no point in doing that in an ASP.NET MVC application.

> I want the long process (creating some documents in the background) to continue running even if the user closes their browser. However if the user still has the browser open then I would like to return a notification to them.

The problem with this is that you'd be [returning early from an ASP.NET request, and (as I describe on my blog), that's quite dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html).

A proper solution would be to queue the work in a reliable queue (e.g., Azure queue or MSMQ), have an independent backend for processing (e.g., Azure worker role / web job or Win32 service), and use something like SignalR for notification.

As soon as you attempt to do work in an ASP.NET process *without* a request context, then you run into the danger that your process may exit without completing the work. If you are OK with this, then you can use the `BackgroundTaskManager` type from my blog above to minimize the chance of that happening (but keep in mind: it *can* still happen).